# Rewrite folder's name using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am wondering wether it's possible to use .htaccess to rewrite a folder name. What I mean is this.

Lets say I have a url like:

```
www.example.org/anyname/page.php
```

Now I want to rewrite the url to (for example)

```
www.example.org/folder1/page.php
```

The folder1 is an existing folder on my webspace.

**important:** the "anyname" is not a folder rather just a name!

Ok here is a step by step plan:

User types `www.site.com/anyname/login.php`.
The url should rewrite and not redirect the url to `www.site.com/folder1/login.php`
This means that "anyname" is just a name and not a directory. All the code should just come from folder1. Acutally "anyname" should just be an alias for folder1. I can't just rename folder1 to "anyname". Therefore I would just rewrite folder1 to "anyname".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.php /folder1/$2.php [L]
```

Comment: Ok I will try it and I answer you. Thanks in advance for your help ;)